# Finding the minimum value in c#

Tags: c#, max

I have this pretty simple code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, pcm, maxm = 0, minm = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if (pcm > maxm)
            maxm = pcm;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your computer marks");
        pcm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

As you can see I have the var pcm and maxm(maximum value), to find the maximum value I got this code : `if (pcm > maxm) maxm = pcm;`, I would like to get the minm(minimum value) in the same way I got the maxm(maximum value).
how could I do that?

Comment: Enter negative values to see your posted code fail the exact same way.  You are not initializing maxm and minm correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the same way you are doing max

```
 int i, pcm, maxm = 0, minm = Int32.MaxValue;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter your computer marks");
        pcm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

       if (pcm > maxm)
        {
           maxm = pcm;
        }

        if (pcm < minm)
        {
           minm = pcm;
        }

    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: set minm = int.maxvalue before the loop

Comment: That's because minM was initialized as 0, Change minM initial value to Int32.MaxValue and it will work.

Comment: It uses a default, `0` value of pcm at the beginning so it's still not correct.

Comment: Sorry, it gives the value (2147483647)!

Comment: Other thing is that You are first comparing, and then reading. It should be other way around, ie first take the input and then compare.

Comment: @System-x32z This answer is wrong... `maxm = 0` is still incorrect.

Comment: @BartoszKP, maxm =0, has no effect. It will impact result only when marks are less than zero, which is not the case.

Comment: @Tilak In the code you've presented this is the case, as anyone running this code can input any number. Maybe OP won't input a negative number, but as a general algorithm for calculating min and max in an iterative way, this is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, pcm, maxm = int.MinValue, minm = int.MaxValue;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your computer marks");
        pcm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        maxm = Math.Max(maxm, pcm);
        minm = Math.Min(minm, pcm);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note the `int.MaxValue` put into `minm` and `int.MinValue` put into `maxm` at their initialization. Also, you were using the default `0` value of `pcm` variable.